# django.shortcuts reverse() call at class var result as error URLconf 'xxx.urls' does does not appear to have any patterns in it

Tags: django, reverse

1.evn

- python3.5
- django2.2

2.problem

- call django.shortcut: reverse() at initializing class variable, compilation is fully ok.
- Got runtime error: The included URLconf 'xxx.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
- Moreover this error message is quite mis-leading, and I spend many time to check the urls which are actually fully correct.

3.Code example

```
from django.views import View
from django.shortcuts import render, reverse, redirect

class LoginView(View):

  main_page = reverse('main')   => cause runtime error

  def get(...):

  def post(...):


urlpatterns = [
    path(r'login/', authviews.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
    path(r'main/', authviews.MainView.as_view(), name='main'),
    ...
```

4.Runtime Error Message

```
File ".../auth/view/views.py", line 10, in <module>
  class LoginView(View):
File ".../auth/view/views.py", line 13, in LoginView
  main_page = reverse('main')
File ".../.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 90, in reverse
  return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))
File ".../.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 600, in _reverse_with_prefix
  self._populate()
File ".../.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 438, in _populate
  for url_pattern in reversed(self.url_patterns):
File ".../.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 80, in __get__
  res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
File ".../.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 580, in url_patterns
  raise ImproperlyConfigured(msg.format(name=self.urlconf_name))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included URLconf 'xxx.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

5.Analysis

- the urls may be not loaded yet when call "reverse()" in class_view

6.Resolution

- way1: use django.urls.reverse_lazy() instead   => suggest way
- way2: move "reverse('main')" call into get() or post()

7.Suggestion

- It would be better to refine the runtime error message to be more accurate

Comment: try move `reverse('main')` to `__init__` method

Comment: Hi. Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer for self-answered questions. The answer should be posted in an *answer*, not as part of the question. And if you want to make suggestions to the Django team, you better look here: https://code.djangoproject.com

Comment: @deceze, thanks a looooot for sharing this message!!  I'll follow this next time :-)